# DOMException has stack in Chrome but not in Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, dom, stack, stack-trace

I'm trying to generate a stacktrace in JavaScript. I have an implementation that works very well in Chrome, but there is an issue in Firefox: native Exceptions like DOMExceptions don't have a `.stack` property.

```
<div id="test"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
try {
    var range = document.createRange();
    range.setStart(document.getElementById("test"), -1); // throws Exception
} catch (e) {
    console.log(e.stack);
}
</script>
```

This will give `Error: Index or size was negative, or greater than the allowed value.
    at http://test/test.html:5:8` in Chrome.

But in Firefox I get `undefined` - sad fais **:(**

I know about [Eriwen's stacktrace script](http://www.eriwen.com/javascript/js-stack-trace/) and [stracktracejs](http://stacktracejs.com/) and my implementation is *inspired* by it. I'll consider using the `caller.callee` fallback but I'd rather not since I can't get the file and line number.

**Do you know a better solution?**

---

I could wrap suspect calls in try-catch statements but I don't know whether a call is suspect before I get the actual error and then I will fix the code so it will never throw again.

I could catch the Exception and rethrow as a `new Error(e.message)` but then I lose the stacktrace as well.

Comment: In Firefox, `e.toString()` seems to give a stack trace. The actual property appears to be `e.location`, but that throws an error when accessed.

Comment: Awesome! I'll look into this. - `e.location` seems to provide a `caller.callee` that is properly populated.

Comment: The format is quite different, though. What are you trying to accomplish? I guess you could also rethrow as `throw e` if that's what you want.

Comment: `e.location` looks like it has what I need when I look at it in Firebug, but when I try to `console.log(e.location);` I get `Error: Permission denied for <file://> to create wrapper for object of class UnnamedClass`. Which seems to be a security related bug .. what? https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=436953

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried `e.location` but this results in a [known bug in Firefox](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=436953). `Error: Permission denied for <file://> to create wrapper for object of class UnnamedClass`.

I *can* access `e.filename` and `e.lineNumber`. This is the solution I'm going with now.